# Jasmine unable to find Spec files

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

In my MEAN project directory, I am trying to run Jasmine unit tests on my express controller. I was initially running node-jasmine however for added functionality I am changing to Jasmine 2.4. However I am running into problems with the location of the jasmine.json, and when I try and workaround, I run into errors in the jasmine source code.

My jasmine.json currently reads:

```
{
    "spec_dir": "spec",
    "spec_files": "**/*[sS]pec.js"
}
```

My file structure is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umQ1w.jpg

my jasmine.json is within support, my model unit tests are in server/controllers/notesSpec.js. If I try to change this with:

```
jasmine JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=test/spec/support/jasmine.json
```

I have tried console logging the source code, some of which you can see below. However, I am still getting the following error:

```
config file path is: /Users/matthewbridges/Projects/markpad/spec/support/jasmine.json
config file is: [object Object]
the spec directory is: undefined
files are: **/*[sS]pec.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:116
  files.forEach(function(specFile) {
    ^

TypeError: files.forEach is not a function
```

pulling the jasmine.json into the default file path still brings up the same errors.

I'll also add the potentially relevant bits of my package.json

scripts:
    "test-jasmine": "jasmine test/server/controllers/notesSpec.js"

```
dev-dependencies: 
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
    "frisby": "^0.8.5",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-express": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-mongo-bin": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-parallel": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.2.5",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.9",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.5.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.6",
    "prettyjson": "^1.1.3",
    "protractor": "^3.2.1",
    "should": "^8.2.2",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^8.0.0"
  }
```

I'll post any other relevant information,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `jasmine.json` is invalid; it should look like this instead:

```
{
    "spec_dir": "spec",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.js"
    ]
}
```