# Jasmine no specs found with more than 13 specs

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Jasmine is reporting a no specs found message after adding a 14th spec to it (doesn't matter if it is a copy of a working spec). If I use a self made reporter it shows that it went through all the specs no problem but that it reports a no specs found as end result.

added a console log to show what I mean

```
Started
[#quickSort]

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
.Passed                should sort small array
.Passed                should hallo small array
.Passed                should sort array with identical values
.Passed                should do nothing with empty array
.Passed                shouldn't sort a string
.Passed                should do nothing with array with single field

Group "#quickSort" was finished


[#signature]

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
[#signature Write signatureformat Remove]

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
.Passed                Compact 1/2; Remove additional x/y members
.Passed                Compact 2/2; Also remove additional x/y members in sequential paths

Group "Write signatureformat Remove" was finished


[#signature Write signatureformat Reposition]

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
.Passed                Reposition 1/2; Reposition top-left to 0,0 for more compact output
.Passed                Reposition 2/2; Reposition top-left to 0,0 for more compact output

Group "Write signatureformat Reposition" was finished


[#signature Write signatureformat Downscale]

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
.Passed                Downscale 1/2; Downscale when needed with minimal resolution loss, so it will never get to large (-2000..2000)
.Passed                Downscale 2/2; Downscale when needed with minimal resolution loss, so it will never get to large (-2000..2000)

Group "Write signatureformat Downscale" was finished


.Passed                Write signatureformat - Complex export
.Passed                Write signatureformat - Rotate 180 degrees

Group "#signature" was finished


Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.002 seconds
```

Also here is the source of the spec_runner

```
//var exit = require('exit');
var Jasmine = require('jasmine'),
    reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var junitReporter = new reporters.NUnitXmlReporter({
  savePath: __dirname,
  consolidateAll: true
});

var myReporter = {

    jasmineStarted: function (suiteInfo) {
    },
    suiteStarted: function (result) {
        console.log('[' + result.fullName + ']');
        console.log('');
        console.log('Results               Top Level Tests');
        console.log('-------               ---------------');
    },
    specStarted: function (result) {
    },
    specDone: function (result) {
        var line = result.status.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.status.substr(1);
        if (line === "Failed") line = "+" + line;
        while (line.length < 22) line += " ";
        console.log(line + result.description);
    },
    suiteDone: function (result) {
        console.log('');
        console.log('Group "' + result.description + '" was ' + result.status);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.failedExpectations.length; i++) {
            console.log('AfterAll ' + result.failedExpectations[i].message);
            console.log(result.failedExpectations[i].stack);
        }
        console.log('');
        console.log('');

        // werkt gewoon niet???? [rv]
        //if (result.status !== "passed") exit(1)
    },
    jasmineDone: function () {
    }
};

var jasmine = new Jasmine();
jasmine.loadConfigFile("spec/support/jasmine.json");
jasmine.addReporter(myReporter);
jasmine.execute();
```

Comment: Provide more information on how you run your tests and provide some config/code files, otherwise it won't be possible to help you. Also try to look for other issues like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208555/jasmine-unable-to-find-spec-files and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it. Problem was in package.json. I used  `"scripts":{"test": "jasmine spec/spec_runner.js"}`

This caused jasmine to run 2 times. Fixed it by using

`"scripts":{"test": "node spec/spec_runner.js"}`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your application compile successfully prior to try running tests.

### Example

I had this error today, for me it was that I had a syntax-level error in my `.ts` files, so they couldn't really compile.

In above situation, I think, the tests should not start (and instead show compile error).

But for whatever reason, somehow the tests start, and `Jasmine` fails with "`No specs found`" log.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the last post but I'm using jasmine-ts:

```
npx jasmine init
```

This will create the following file if it doesn't already exist:

```
spec/support/jasmine.json
```

The initial contents didn't fit the bill for me so I had to go with the following, paying particular attention to the spec_dir (relative to your package.json where you run the tests command from):

```
{
  "spec_dir": "./",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "random": false,
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "reporters": [
    {
      "name": "jasmine-spec-reporter#SpecReporter",
      "options": {
        "suite": {
          "displayNumber": true
        },
        "spec": {
          "displayStacktrace": "pretty",
          "displayDuration": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "jasmine-reporters#JUnitXmlReporter",
      "options": {
        "savePath": ".",
        "consolidateAll": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this issue I used this command in the appropriate folder:

```
$jasmine init
```

It's simple but it worked for me.

Comment: What is an "appropriate" folder?

Comment: @Gi1ber7 project root